# How to process HttpResponseBody in Haskell req?

Tags: haskell, haskell-req

I have an application that gets JSON response from an API and I'm trying to get a specific key from that response. The working code looks as below:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

module Main (main) where
import Data.Aeson
import Network.HTTP.Req
   
tinyUIDRequest :: String -> Req (JsonResponse Object)
tinyUIDRequest url = let payload = object [ "url" .= url ] 
                 in req 
                    POST 
                    (https "tinyuid.com" /: "api" /: "v1" /: "shorten") (
                    ReqBodyJson payload) 
                    jsonResponse
                    mempty           

main :: IO ()
main = do 
    response <- runReq defaultHttpConfig (tinyUIDRequest "http://google.com")
    let body = responseBody response
    print body
```

And the function to process the response should look similar to:

```
tinyUIDResponseHandler :: HttpResponseBody (JsonResponse Object) -> String
tinyUIDResponseHandler r = case lookup "result_url" r of 
                            Just url -> url
                            Nothing -> ""
```

unfortunately I'm not able to figure out how to transform `HttpResponseBody (JsonResponse Object)` to something like hashmap/list and find a proper key. I was checking [the documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/req-3.9.0/docs/Network-HTTP-Req.html) and [req source code](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/req-3.2.0/docs/src/Network.HTTP.Req.html) but maybe, as a beginner in Haskell, I don't know exactly what to look for to understand the internals of the response type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`HttpResponseBody` is a red herring. It's an associated type, and `HttpResponseBody (JsonResponse a)` is the same as just `a`, so `HttpResponseBody (JsonResponse Object)` is really just `Object`. As such, once you have `body`, `req`'s job is done, and it's now just `aeson` that you need to be concerned with.

Since `body` is an `Object` and not a list of tuples, you can't use Prelude's `lookup` on it. If your Aeson version is older than 2, then [`Object`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-1.5.6.0/docs/Data-Aeson.html#t:Object) is just `HashMap Text Value`, so do this instead:

```
import Data.Text
import qualified Data.HashMap.Strict as HM

tinyUIDResponseHandler :: Object -> Text
tinyUIDResponseHandler r = case HM.lookup "result_url" r of 
                            Just (String url) -> url
                            _ -> ""
```

If your Aeson version is 2 or newer, then [`Object`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-2.0.2.0/docs/Data-Aeson.html#t:Object) is `KeyMap Value`, so do this instead:

```
import Data.Text
import qualified Data.Aeson.KeyMap as AKM

tinyUIDResponseHandler :: Object -> Text
tinyUIDResponseHandler r = case AKM.lookup "result_url" r of 
                            Just (String url) -> url
                            _ -> ""
```

In either case, `tinyUIDResponseHandler body` will then be the value you want, so for example, you could do `print (tinyUIDResponseHandler body)`.

Comment: "`(JsonResponse a)` is the same as just `a`" - I'm not sure why you say this, it can't be pattern matched as `a`.

Comment: @ChrisStryczynski That's not what I said. I said "`HttpResponseBody (JsonResponse a)` is the same as just `a`".

Comment: @ChrisStryczynski I suspect your actual problem is that my answer was written for Aeson 1.x, and in Aeson 2, `Object` is no longer a `HashMap Text Value`. I'll update my answer to explain that.

Comment: Ah sorry my bad, in which case it does actually pattern match (though it seems strange to me that it would). Is this a feature of "associated types" with type families?

Comment: @ChrisStryczynski That's exactly what type families are. For a minimal example, do `type family UnMaybe t where UnMaybe (Maybe a) = a`, then you can write `one = 1 :: UnMaybe (Maybe Int)` and it'll be exactly the same as `one = 1 :: Int`.